# how to change directory in ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04, symbolic-link

I'm trying to change the directories of a symbolic link.

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql-cluster-gpl-7.1.5-linux-i686-glibc23 /usr/local/mysql
```

When I type command **cd /usr/local/mysql** it is giving me error

```
root@lucky:cd /usr/local/mysql
bash: cd: mysql: No such file or directory
```

and my ls output is

```
root@lucky:~# ls -la /usr/local/

drwxr-xr-x  6 root   root        4096 Dec 15 16:22 lib
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root           9 Nov 12 10:18 man -> share/man
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root         45 Apr 25 14:27 mysql -> mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.3-    linux-glibc2.5-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x 13 root   root        4096 Apr 25 17:35 mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.5-linux-    glibc2.5-x86_64
-rw-------  1 root  root  470438560 Apr 25 14:24 mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.5-linux-    glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root        4096 Aug 20  2013 sbin
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Doesn't look like a standard cd to me....what is '-su:' ?

Comment: it is error ..... -su: cd: mysql: No such file or directory

Comment: ok....but if you did a standard cd on a command line you are not going to see "-su:"....SOOOOO what is the actual command line you used?

Comment: cd /usr/local/mysql

Comment: Maybe `cd` is an alias?

Comment: @Barmar sorry i didn't understand your last comment

Comment: When you type `cd` you get an error message from `su`. That makes me think you've created an alias named `cd` that expands into `su`.

Comment: @davidgo i stop apparmor but error is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Symlink is incorrect.

Your symlink for mysql goes to "mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.3-" but the version of mysql-cluster is mysql-cluster-gpl-7.3.5-linux-    (not 7.3.5 vs 7.3.3)

Try RM the symlink and recreate it.

Comment: Even stranger, the `ln -s` command refers to `7.1.5`. How did the symlink end up pointing to a different file?